# VS Code brings search result line to the center of the screen

Tags: visual-studio-code

When you search for a keyword in VS Code, and it returns x results, as you start browsing among those results, the screen always centers vertically the active result on the screen. This may be useful in some situations, but in cases where I want to "frame" all my results in the same active screen, it's very annoying that it jumps the code, even by 2-3 lines...

OK, if in that viewable portion of the code there are no results, and I click on the next result, it'd make sense to bring me to the first one. But if let's say 4-5 results are already in the viewable portion of the code, I would like to set it so that it prevents that centering all the time. So is there such a setting?

I hope I explained it well enough so that you understand what I mean. TIA for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is configurable if the next find match is outside of the viewport.  I see this in the code:

(https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/7a0a293b38c353cd9773316a022d8f926d481715/src/vs/editor/contrib/find/browser/findModel.ts)

```js
    private _setCurrentFindMatch(match: Range): void {
        let matchesPosition = this._decorations.setCurrentFindMatch(match);
        this._state.changeMatchInfo(
            matchesPosition,
            this._decorations.getCount(),
            match
        );

        this._editor.setSelection(match);
        this._editor.revealRangeInCenterIfOutsideViewport(match, ScrollType.Smooth);
    }
```

So `revealRangeInCenterIfOutsideViewport()` will always put the next find match into the center if it is not initially not in the viewport.

In the search code, there is the similar:

`this.searchResultEditor.revealLineInCenterIfOutsideViewport(matchRange.startLineNumber);`

So I would think there is no scrolling if the next serach result is already in view.

For me, there is no scrolliing at all if the next find match is anywhere in the viewport.  Do you see some scrolling if it is at the very bottom, for example?

Comment: Even if it's off center by 2-3 lines, it always scrolls it to the center. Take a look at this video I recorded from my desktop https://streamable.com/62pktq

Comment: Ah, you are doing a search from the Panel - I thought you were doing a find so that is the code snippet I found.  But I bet the search is very similar.

Comment: TBH, yes, I was referring to the panel mostly, as that's what I'm using when I'm trying to find my way through exploring an unknown functionality of a given API - by searching keywords and seeing what's calling what... In the Page search, now that you mention it, I think it doesn't do it like that.